# Internet Explorer & Directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an AngularJS (1.3.9) project and everything runs well on all browsers expected on Internet Explorer (9, 10 and 11) — but it works well on Internet Explorer mobile….

The symptoms are:

- the app and the templates are loaded
- cpu is @ 100%
- dynamic data are not displayed.

I did many tests and isolated a piece of code that seems to hang…

HTML code :

```
<ul class="schedules">
        <li ng-repeat="schedule in schedules | limitTo:2" class="schedule {{ ::schedule.channelLogo }}">
            <img class="channel-logo {{ ::schedule.channelLogo }}" ng-src="{{getChannelLogoSrc(schedule.channelLogo)}}" />

            {{schedule}}
            <hr>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The directive associated with:

```
schedulesDirectives
    .directive('schedules', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/schedules/partials/schedules.html',
            scope: {
                displayPart: "@",
                schedules: "=data",
                carousel: "=",
                prevSlide: "&",
                nextSlide: "&"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.getChannelLogoSrc = function(channelLogo) {
                    // return adequate size depending on device
                    return "/img/channel-logo/" + channelLogo + "." + scope.carousel.logoType;
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

If I change the ng-src with a static src that works fine. Why?
Other strange thing: the getChannelLogoSrc function should be called 2x (limitTO:2), but it is called 10x.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not running IE in some kind of compatibliyu mode, or quirks mode ?

Comment: Yes, for the compatibility mode. What do you mean by "quirks mode" ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: Ok, more infos.
If I change the return line in the link function by hardcoding channelLogo that works !!!
But, channelLogo is never empty… so I do not understand…

Comment: as far as i noticed, functions in template get called on every watches you have in templates, like 4 interpolations, one ng-repeat, 5 x 2 = 10, sometimes randomly, or sometimes more.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even create a function and call it from the template? Looks far to expensive for what your trying to achieve.

I'd suggest setting the url in the `link` function and assigning it in the template - the one-time-bindings in the template make me feel like the image won't change either:

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.imageUrl = "/img/channel-logo/" + schedule.channelLogo + "." + scope.carousel.logoType;
}
```

and

```
<img class="channel-logo {{ ::schedule.channelLogo }}" ng-src="{{ ::imageUrl }}" />
```

> Other strange thing: the getChannelLogoSrc function should be called 2x (limitTO:2), but it is called 10x.

You don't provide a `track by` expression for the `ngRepeat`, so the items are re-rendered every time `schedules` changes.